# What do you call the remains of a wave, the part that reaches the shore?

Tags: single-word-requests

> I like to play at the beach chasing the [...] by the shoreline.

I think *tides* isn't the word, because it refers to the slow changes on the shore. And *waves*, I think they are bigger and are in the sea?

Comment: These are called *waves*. You could call this meeting the *shoreline*. Waves *lap* or *crash* upon the shoreline.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Also *roll in* to the shoreline?

Comment: Absolutely. There are quite a few words that can be used to describe the interaction.

Comment: A wave devolves into ripples.

Comment: Could you describe more precisely the word you're looking for? If you mean "What is a wave called when it's very close to the shore?", the answer is "a wave."

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I've always called it ***surf***.

> the mass or line of foam formed by waves breaking on a seashore or reef.

Definition from [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/surf)

Answer (score 24):

You can also call them-
**[breaker](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=breakers%20meaning&hl=en-IN&gbv=2&oq=&gs_l=)**, **breakers**, or *surf*

- [waves breaking on the shore](http://fineartamerica.com/featured/2-waves-breaking-on-tropical-shore-elena-elisseeva.html)
- a heavy sea wave that breaks into white foam on the shore. (MW)

Answer (score 10):

In British English, I would call the dying flow of a wave on a beach *wash*.

Google also appears to confirm this:

> noun: wash
>
> the surging of water or breaking of waves or the sound made by this.
>
> "the wash of waves on the pebbled beach"
>
> synonyms:   surge, flow, swell,
>   sweep, rise and fall, roll, splash

#### EDIT

Although this may be incorrect, and more correctly attributed to the sound. From the [Oxford English Dictionary entry for *wash*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/225922?rskey=NeS0hR&result=1#eid)

> c. The sound of the surge of water.
>
> 1845   J. Coulter Adventures Pacific ix. 109,   I..listened to the wash of the briny element on the beach.
>
> 1871   H. W. Longfellow in S. Longfellow Life H. W. Longfellow (1891) III. 177   The low wash of the sea very soothing.
>
> 1873   W. Black Princess of Thule iii. 45   The wash of the ripples along the coast could be heard.
>
> 1918   Blackwood's Mag. June 717/2   The wash of the swell on rocks met my ear.

Answer (score 9):

I found a [site on surfing in Hawaii](http://www.alohasurfguide.com/know-the-waves/) that calls that backwash, whitewash, and soup.

Comment: I would consider those more informal or slang.

Comment: Possibly surfers' jargon: these aren't  really in common use.

Comment: Another one is the "foam"

Answer (score 5):

"Surf" has been accepted as an answer, and "waves" has been proposed a few times, but both words refer to a far broader concept than what the OP asks about.

A "wave" is the rolling shape which is formed far out at sea by the action of the wind on the surface of the water. None of the water in waves actually moves very far, it is the shape which is propagates towards land.

"Waves" become "surf" from the point at which they first begin to break (according to [the dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/surf), and in general surfer parlance), although of course they'll still be referred to as "waves".

Finally, when surf reaches shallow water, and the rotational force of the original wave has been eliminated by friction with the shore and the air, it is reduced to a surge of foamy water which washes up the beach, and the recedes again, referreed to as "swash" on the way in, and "backwash" on the way out. ([Wikipedia page for Swash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swash))

Comment: Even if 'swash' is the technical term used by those needing to make a fine distinction, 'surf' and 'waves' would be the terms in more common usage. This matches the 2nd definition at the dictionary.com entry you've linked.

Answer (score 3):

Acknowledging that **wave** and **surf** might also fit the purpose...

Wave **run-up** and **run-out** are terms that I think correspond to what you are talking about - the almost flat influx of water at the far reach of a wave on the beach.

A technical term that could easily be used is **swash**, the inrush of water due to a wave.

An associated term that I like and rarely see is **spume**, the froth caused by wave/surf action.

Answer (score 2):

**Wavelets** would be accurate.
I like to play at the beach chasing the [wavelets] by the shoreline.

Answer (score 1):

A possible variant is **beachcomber**, [from Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/beachcomber):

> A long wave rolling in from the sea

Though I think this word is much more often used in its other meaning:

> A vagrant who makes a living by searching beaches for articles of value and selling them.

I would simply go with **wave**.

Comment: Long curling/breaking waves are sometimes called **combers** (although this is getting fairly rare itself).  **Beachcomber** has pretty exclusively referred to people for many many years.